# Twitter Bootstrap with Scalatags

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scala, scalatags

Apologies in advance for the vague question, however I need some assistance. I am new to Scalatags, and Scala in general and I am looking for a means of using Twitter's Bootstrap library with Scalatags generated HTML.

I have yet to see a documented case of this being done, and the Scalatags documentation itself is a little on the light side. I'd prefer not to have to code all of the styles manually, certainly not via ScalaCSS. The application I am developing is to act as a companion to other applications styled with Bootstrap, so there is a requirement to keep the interfaces somewhat uniform.

I am working with the JVM flavour of Scala in the backend and wish to steer clear of Scala.JS if possible. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple to solve in the end, just needed the following:

```
 head(
    link(href := "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css", rel := "stylesheet"),
  )
```